# Delete elements with specific field from list (r language)

Tags: r

I have a vector of lists in it. Every list contain field `category`
I need delete all lists with fields `category == resource`.

I tried

```
for(i in 1:length(myList)){
  if(myList[[as.numeric(i)]]$data$category == "resource"){
    myList[[as.numeric(i)]]<-NULL
  }
}
```

Is it correct?

```
> dput(myList[1:2])
list(structure(list(data = structure(list(device = "iPad2,4", 
    os_version = "ios 7.1.2", connection_type = "wifi", category = "user", 
    platform = "ios", session_num = 2, ios_idfv = "E12AA218-4061-4BA1-AFA3-47FEE1511C2E", 
    client_ts = 1454926346, sdk_version = "unity 2.4.3", limited_ad_tracking = TRUE, 
    user_id = "436E8588-B2FA-411A-896C-5757E7A2A377", manufacturer = "apple", 
    jailbroken = TRUE, ios_idfa = "436E8588-B2FA-411A-896C-5757E7A2A377", 
    build = "1.0", session_id = "558910f2-7c2c-4280-84fc-2fef1a50d291", 
    v = 2, engine_version = "unity 4.6.9"), .Names = c("device", 
"os_version", "connection_type", "category", "platform", "session_num", 
"ios_idfv", "client_ts", "sdk_version", "limited_ad_tracking", 
"user_id", "manufacturer", "jailbroken", "ios_idfa", "build", 
"session_id", "v", "engine_version")), first_in_batch = TRUE, 
    country_code = "RO", arrival_ts = 1454926344, game_id = 24540, 
    ip = "93.168.249.0"), .Names = c("data", "first_in_batch", 
"country_code", "arrival_ts", "game_id", "ip")), structure(list(
    data = structure(list(os_version = "ios 9.2.1", engine_version = "unity 4.6.9", 
        category = "user", v = 2, ios_idfa = "F06962FE-FCE5-475F-8CC2-83FF1F89E573", 
        sdk_version = "unity 2.4.3", user_id = "F06962FE-FCE5-475F-8CC2-83FF1F89E573", 
        session_num = 2, platform = "ios", connection_type = "wifi", 
        manufacturer = "apple", client_ts = 1454925528, limited_ad_tracking = TRUE, 
        session_id = "3ab1fbbb-5103-4ad8-bf56-94f70fea94a7", 
        device = "iPad4,1", ios_idfv = "2C940E82-B074-4A15-B9A7-A5983759042F", 
        build = "1.0"), .Names = c("os_version", "engine_version", 
    "category", "v", "ios_idfa", "sdk_version", "user_id", "session_num", 
    "platform", "connection_type", "manufacturer", "client_ts", 
    "limited_ad_tracking", "session_id", "device", "ios_idfv", 
    "build")), first_in_batch = TRUE, country_code = "AU", arrival_ts = 1454925528, 
    game_id = 24540, ip = "110.175.52.0"), .Names = c("data", 
"first_in_batch", "country_code", "arrival_ts", "game_id", "ip"
)))
```

Comment: Try `lapply(myList, setdiff, "resource")`  Please show a small reproducible example.  We don't know what you meant by `field`.  Do you have a `data.frame` or `matrix` or `vector` as each `list` element?

Comment: Can you post a dput output of `dput(myList[1:2])` and the expected output so that it becomes easier for others to test it?

Comment: @arkun i need to have all vector except lists where myList$data$category == "resource"

Comment: your example has no `category = "ressource"`.

Comment: In the example you provided, `category` is "user"

Comment: yeah! It's not this case

Comment: Just a doubt, did you meant to remove the `list` element that has "resource" in "category" or only just the `category` part

Comment: @akrun I meant to remove the whole list(not only "category" part)

Comment: In that case the `Filter` should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `rlist` package :

```
library(rlist)
filtered_list <- list.exclude(myList, data$category == "ressource")
```

Answer (score 0):

We could use `Filter` from `base R`

```
Filter(function(x) x$data$category!="resource", myList)
```